# Sharepoint OSS 2010 on Sql Server Express?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-express

Can SharePoint 2010 OSS run on Sql Server Express?

What are the pros, cons and limitations?  This will not be a huge repository, but we do want to do basic things like workflows.

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: Do you mean SharePoint Server 2010? The name change from Microsoft Office SharePoint Server is a little confusing. They dropped the Office Part.

Comment: Yes that is the one.  darned marketers like to change names to confuse the technically challenged!

Comment: It took me some time to get used to, but now I'm perfectly happy to drop the office bit. Plus, it makes differentiating between the two products easier. Now we have SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Server instead of Windows SharePoint Services and Microsoft Office SharePoint Server. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can install with SQL Server 2008 Express with SP1 or higher. Install SQL Express first and specify the instance name when configuring SharePoint. I don't recommend the standalone install, but it uses SQL Server Express by default.

According to Wikipedia [SQL Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) has these limits:

- Maximum database size of 4 GB per database (increased to 10 GB for SQL Server Express 2008 R2[2]) (compared to 2 GB in the former MSDE). The limit applies per database (log files excluded); but in some scenarios users can access more data through the use of multiple interconnected databases.
- Hardware-utilization limits: Single physical CPU, but multiple cores allowable[3]
- 1 GB of RAM (runs on a system with any RAM amount, but uses only at most 1GB)
  Absence of the SQL Server Agent service